# libraries are not working pycharm python?

Tags: python, pycharm, libraries

I've been trying to fix it for hours now, tried everything, saw a post about changing the directory tried it and it still doesn't work. pls help(the post said add 'lib\site-packages 'which is in the image I attached)

before anyone asks, my PyCharm is up to date, so is visual studio

the libraries I am trying to use are 'requests' and beautiful Soup
and I can verify this via running installation again and it'll show me that module is already installed.

Comment: On the bottom right of your IDE there should be some small text like `Python 3.10` or something. Click on it, and then you can change the path to your python interpreter that has these packages installed. In your terminal, assuming that you are using the python that has these packages installed, you can type `which python` to see what you should point your Pycharm interpreter towards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.